# How to set a dynamic table be scrollable in a dynamic fixed size, determined by the viewport and a neighbor div?

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm using Preact with Tailwind and daisyUI to make my app. The idea is that the screen will have two tabs, each tab has one textarea on the left and instruction/result on the right.

I use daisyUI's [radio tab lifted + tab content](https://daisyui.com/components/tab/#radio-tab-lifted--tab-content) for tabbing, together with Tailwind's [`columns-2`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns#adding-based-on-column-width) for each tab panel for columns:

```html
<div role="tablist" className="tabs tabs-lifted tabs-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" className="tab" aria-label="Tab 1" />
  <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 columns-2">
    <Tab1 />
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" className="tab" aria-label="Tab 2" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 columns-2">
    <Tab2 />
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem mostly in tab 2, where I have a textarea on the left and a table on the right. Its numbers of rows and columns will be vary. I use this daisyUI's [table with pinned-rows and pinned-cols](https://daisyui.com/components/table/#table-with-pinned-rows-and-pinned-cols) code:

```html
<textarea
  rows={15}
  cols={40}
/><br />
<div className="overflow-x-auto">
  <table className="table table-xs table-pin-rows table-pin-cols">
...
```

When there is no table to display yet, the result is as expected:

[image]

However, when table appears it is pushed far away, and the tab lables width are shrunk:

[image]

If I don't use `columns-2` but `grid grid-cols-4` the table is not pushed far away anymore, but the result is still not desired:

[image]

Even when I try `flex shrink w-30` for the table, it is still not shrunk.

I have tried to disable all the style from the devtool but still can't figure out the reasons for these behaviors.

My goal is to have everything in one screen:

- The table width is to be fixed with the rest of the width of the screen,
- The table height not limited, but its maximum is equal to the textarea
- There is a footer with fixed height. The textarea height should fill the gap between the tab name and the footer
- On phones the table should be below the textarea. The width should be fixed and scrollable, while the height has no limit
- (Optional) The widths of the textarea and the table are divided harmonically: if the sum of them is smaller than the viewport width, then the ratio between the two should equal the golden ratio and center in the screen. If not, then the minimum width of the textarea should be 40.

I guess that these can be achieved with flex or grid, but at first I need fix the above problem.

Comment: "The table height not limited, but its maximum is equal to the textarea" – this seems like a contradictory statement. It seems like the table height **is** limited, to a maximum of the textarea, no? "There is a footer with fixed height." – consider providing a fuller example with the footer. To be able to have the textarea height full the gap between the tab name and the footer, we'd need to see the page layout with the footer and the tabs. "On phones" – phones come in all shapes and sizes. Consider providing a media query breakpoint instead of this ambiguous term

Comment: Yes, the table height is limited, to a maximum of the text area. I haven't made the footer yet but it's simply a div at the bottom of the viewport, with full viewport width. I'd use the common breakpoint like 500px for phones

Comment: Consider also providing a full example of a table please.

Comment: "Its numbers of rows and columns will be vary", so I guess any table is fine? You can use any table that you can generate, for example from [this table generator](https://divtable.com/generator/). Or do you mean the JSX code I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having a child element of the `.tab-content` element that has the grid layout. This is because `.tab-content` has `display` properties to hide or show its content, so it is best not to interfere with the `display` property.

We can apply something like `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr` to have the first grid column track be as wide as the `<textarea>` and then the remaining content to be the remaining space available.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.6.0/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted tabs-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1" />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    Tab 1
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 2" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 min-[500px]:grid-cols-[min-content_1fr] gap-5">
      <textarea rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      <div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <table class="table table-xs table-pin-rows table-pin-cols">
          <!-- head -->
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Job</th>
              <th>Favorite Color</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- row 1 -->
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
              <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- row 2 -->
            <tr>
              <th>2</th>
              <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
              <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
              <td>Purple</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- row 3 -->
            <tr>
              <th>3</th>
              <td>Brice Swyre</td>
              <td>Tax Accountant</td>
              <td>Red</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To have the height of the table be maximally the same as the `<textarea>`, we can make it absolutely-positioned so that we can guarantee it does not participate in layout calculations of the grid. I'll also assume this stipulation only applies when the `<textarea>` and the table are side-by-side (above `500px` viewport width). I'll also assume you'd want to be able to scroll vertically through the table and thus replace `overflow-x: auto` with `overflow: auto`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.6.0/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted tabs-lg">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1" />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    Tab 1
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 2" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 min-[500px]:grid-cols-[min-content_1fr] gap-5">
      <textarea rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      <div class="relative">
        <div class="min-[500px]:absolute inset-0 overflow-auto">
          <table class="table table-xs table-pin-rows table-pin-cols">
            <!-- head -->
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
                <th>Favorite Color</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 1 -->
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 2 -->
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                <td>Purple</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- row 3 -->
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                <td>Red</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally StackOverflow, one should focus on one problem only, so I should not address the query about the layout of the footer, but I digress.

We can use a vertical flex layout to ensure the height of the `<textarea>` (and by extension, the table) fills any empty space between the tab headers and this imaginary footer. We'll need to adjust the grid layout within the `.tabs` too, so that the tabs are pinned to the top with the `.tab-content` stretched out as needed:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.6.0/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted tabs-lg grow grid-rows-[max-content]">
    <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1" />
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 min-h-0 self-stretch">
      Tab 1
    </div>

    <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 2" checked />
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 min-h-0 self-stretch">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 min-[500px]:grid-cols-[min-content_1fr] gap-5 h-full">
        <textarea rows="15" cols="40" class="h-full"></textarea>
        <div class="relative">
          <div class="min-[500px]:absolute inset-0 overflow-auto">
            <table class="table table-xs table-pin-rows table-pin-cols">
              <!-- head -->
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Job</th>
                  <th>Favorite Color</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                  <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 2 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Hart Hagerty</td>
                  <td>Desktop Support Technician</td>
                  <td>Purple</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- row 3 -->
                <tr>
                  <th>3</th>
                  <td>Brice Swyre</td>
                  <td>Tax Accountant</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: The table is hidden on phones. In `<div class="relative"><div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-auto">`, why do you split into 2 divs just to declare the classes? Why not merge them into one, or even into the table class? At some point the problems of table being pushed far away and the tab lables width being shrunk are solved. Where are that points, and why do they happen at the first place?

Comment: "The table is hidden on phones." – fixed. I split into 2 `div` elements so that the first is a position parent for the second. One could not merge them. The table being pushed far away was because the equidistant layout columns generated through `columns-2`. I could not recreate the tab labels behavior you describe with your original code.

Comment: Can you try using long tab names? The shrinking tab name still happens when you are on phones. I guess they need to be on separate lines in this case. Also, how to get the textarea width to simply fill the viewport width on phones?

Comment: "The shrinking tab name still happens when you are on phones." – you'd want to adjust the `.tabs` grid layout to work how you want. "how to get the textarea width to simply fill the viewport width" – apply the appropriate `width`.

Comment: What I wonder is that if Tailwind is mobile-first, then why do these bugs happen on phones only but not on larger screens? What does `grid-rows-[max-content]` do? I cannot find any result about `[max-content]` on [the Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-row "Grid Row Start / End - Tailwind CSS")

Comment: "What I wonder is that if Tailwind is mobile-first, then why do these bugs happen on phones only but not on larger screens?" I'd say it's more a "bug" with Flowbite and their CSS structure, rather than Tailwind itself. I assume Flowbite has to make some compromise and assume the common tab label length is shorter than what you have. `grid-rows-[max-content]` applies `grid-template-rows: max-content`, see this syntax in the [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows#arbitrary-values).

Comment: how do I set the table to only be side-by-side to the textarea when the remaining width of the screen is at least double the minimum width of the textarea?